# EJB 3.1 JSR definition

Tags: ejb, jndi, jsr

In the EJB 3.1 JSR it states in section 16.3.4

> The container must ensure that the enterprise bean instances have
>   only read access to their environment variables. The container must
>   throw the javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException from all the
>   methods of the javax.naming.Context interface that modify the
>   environment naming context and its subcontexts.

**Question 1**: According to the JSR, It is not legal to add/edit an object, lets say the string "hello", to JNDI from a stateless bean method?

So the following code should fail if that is true, but when testing in it in my jboss 6 it works just fine.

```
public void RebindVars() throws NamingException{
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    String testString = (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/testString");
    String newString = "helloRebindFromJndi"; //Assume that this is a valid call.
    if (!testString.equals(newString)) {
        ctx.rebind("java:comp/env/testString", newString);
    }
}
```

**Question 2**: Since it works in my jboss is it the implementation of jboss that allows more then required or have I totally misunderstood the JSR?

I'm taking the EJB certification and thats why i´m asking this so no need to comment on why I ever would do this =)

Answer (score 1):

I do believe what EJB specification says is true. The ENC is a read-only naming space - try it on JBoss AS 7.1.1 and it should fail.

Some further reading which you might be interested in:

- [ENC and JNDI relation - Javaranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/536918/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/EJB-questions-newbie)
- [Automatic JNDI implementation - JBoss AS 7](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-421)